# group by sql server, multiples columnas

Tags: sql-server, group-by

estoy intentando realizar un group by de este modo, pero no logro el resultado que quiero. Quisiera que el resultado este en una sola fila.
Espero puedan ayudarme.

```
Select GUIA_DET_NRO_REF,
case car_ind_fc when 0 then count(car_ind_fc) end AS pendientes,
case car_ind_fc when 1 then count(car_ind_fc) end AS facturadas,
case car_ind_fc when 2 then count(car_ind_fc) end as Anuladas
from guia_DEtalle_nacional gdn with(nolock)
group by   GUIA_DET_NRO_REF,car_ind_fc
```

[image: Resultado no deseado]

Comment: Prueba de este modo: `group by   GUIA_DET_NRO_REF, pendientes, facturadas, Anuladas;`

Comment: Considero te sería funcional pues por cada `CASE` estas generando una columna con valores nuevos, entonces en este caso en lugar de agrupar por la columna original de la tabla hazlo por aquellas que se estan generando producto del condicional

Comment: Bueno para no extenderme en los comentarios y como no se me ocurre otra idea pensaría en pasar los `CASE` en el área del `GROUP BY` para evitar el error de que las columnas no existan por ser los alias los invocados, si eso no da :) no tengo al momento mas opciones pero marcaré la pregunta y le daré un +1 para saber la solución

Comment: Logre hacerlo, de este modo: Select GUIA_DET_NRO_REF,count(*)CantidadTotal,
sum (case when car_ind_fc=0 then 1 else 0 end )pendientes,
sum (case when car_ind_fc=1 then 1 else 0 end )facturadas,
sum (case when car_ind_fc=2 then 1 else 0 end )anuladas
from guia_DEtalle_nacional gdn with(nolock) group by   GUIA_DET_NRO_REF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que buscas es un recuento condicional:

```
SELECT GUIA_DET_NRO_REF,
       COUNT(CASE car_ind_fc WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE END) AS pendientes,
       COUNT(CASE car_ind_fc WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE END) AS facturadas,
       COUNT(CASE car_ind_fc WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE END) AS Anuladas
       FROM guia_DEtalle_nacional gdn with(nolock)
       GROUP BY GUIA_DET_NRO_REF
```

Notas

- La condición va dentro del `COUNT()`
- El agrupamiento solo por `GUIA_DET_NRO_REF`